# Permission denied when using PAM login for RStudio Server

Tags: rstudio-server

I cannot log into RStudio Server using my username through PAM. The login returned an "Error: Incorrect or invalid username/password" error. I've copied and overwritten `/etc/pam.d/rstudio` with `/etc/pam.d/login`.

In `/var/log/syslog`, the error is logged as:

```
rserver[10096]: ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied) [user-value=<my username>]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::user::{anonymous}::userFrom(const boost::function<int(T, passwd*, char*, long unsigned int, passwd**)>&, T, rstudio::core::system::user::User*) [with T = const char*] /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system/PosixUser.cpp:107; LOGGED FROM: std::string rstudio::server::pam_auth::{anonymous}::userIdentifierToLocalUsername(const string&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerPAMAuth.cpp:175
```

`sudo rstudio-server verify-installation` returns no error.

`sudo pamtester --verbose rstudio <my username> authenticate` logs in successfully with no error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The issue seems to be transient and hence a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

First step:

open file /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf using command something like:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf
```

and ten add the below line:

```
auth-required-user-group=analysts,admins,rstudio-users
```

exit using:

```
:wq
```

Creating and managing group membership
To create a new group you use the groupadd command:

```
$ sudo groupadd <groupname>   (e.g. $ sudo groupadd rstudio-users)
```

Then To add a user to an existing group you use the usermod command:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G <groupname> <username>  (e.g. $ sudo usermod -a -G rstudio-users rstudiouser)
```

Then Stop and Start Server:

```
$ sudo rstudio-server stop
$ sudo rstudio-server start
```

I did this and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when the authenticated user does not exist on the Rstudio Server. For instance, when you have configured an external LDAP authentication through PAM.